# On Safari only, a focus outline is appearing upon clicking of slider element

Tags: css, safari, focus, accessibility, tiny-slider

The site where this is occurring:
https://elearning.scranton.edu/

On safari desktop and mobile, if you scroll down to the program slider and click on the arrows you will see the *entire* slider module receives a grey dotted focus outline. I can't figure out why this happening. This outline should only be happening upon tabbing with the keyboard not upon clicking. I don't want to completely remove the :focus styling as this leaves keyboard users with no indication of where they are on the screen.  I cant figure out why this is happening. The slider in use is Tiny Slider but i don't see anything in the docs related to focus outline and safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're talking about the carousel.  If you click on the left or right buttons, the entire carousel gets a dotted focus indicator.

[image: screenshot from iphone showing carousel with focus indicator]

This is because the carousel `<div>` has a `tabindex="0"` whereas the actual arrow buttons do not (`tabindex="-1"`), so the focus ends up going to the carousel and receives a dotted outline.  Firefox and Chrome are allowing the focus to move to the `<button>` when you click on them even though they have `tabindex="-1"` so you don't (initially) see the dotted outline on the carousel container itself but you **can** see the same outline if you <kbd>tab</kbd> backwards after clicking on one of the arrows.

Here's a Firefox screenshot:

[image: screenshot from firefox]

I'm not sure why there's a difference in behavior but it does show an accessibility problem with the site.  The left/right arrow buttons should **not** have  `tabindex="-1"`.  A keyboard user has no (obvious) way to navigate to the buttons and move to the next carousel item.  If you play around with it, you eventually find that when you <kbd>tab</kbd> to the carousel (`<div tabindex="0">`), you can then use the left and right keyboard arrow keys to scroll the carousel left and right.

So if you remove `tabindex="-1"` from the `<button>` elements, I suspect you'll get the same focus behavior on all browsers.

I'm guessing you want to keep the `tabindex="0"` on the carousel (third party library?) to allow the left/right arrow keys to scroll the carousel, although if the buttons are keyboard focusable, the left/right arrow keys are superfluous.